# Showing a counterexample regarding normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

For field extensions K/E, E/F, if K/F is a normal extension, E/F is a normal extension also?
I think this is false..but can't find a counterexample. Could anyone suggest me some example?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $K$ the splitting field of $x^{3}-2$, and $E = F(\sqrt[3]{2})$. $K$ is a normal extension of $F$, and $K$ is a normal extension of $E$ since one can show $K$ is a quadratic extension of $E$. But $E$ is not a normal extension of $F$.

Comment: Hardly a 'hint' though.

Comment: @GitGud: my bad. Sometimes I get insecure about whether what I am posting is right, and end up fleshing out the details just to make sure I haven't missed something... :) (To be fair, there is a bit of work to be done in computing the splitting field of $x^{3}-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.)

Comment: I'd rather read a good counterexample than a "hint" anyway!

Answer (score 2):

**Have some intuition**:

An extension $K/F$ is Galois if and only if $K$ is both separable and normal.  Further, all extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are separable.

If your statement is true, this would imply that *all* algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are Galois.  Equivalently, this would imply that every algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a splitting field for some irreducible polynomial with coefficients over the rationals.  Needless to say, this is a contradiction.